# "in proportion" What does it mean?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, expressions, meaning-in-context

A: I like having a MINI Cooper. I sort of identify with it. You know? It's pretty little. I feel as if it's proportion... that we are **in proportion**, you know? Me and my car, we are sort of... together, facing the rest of the world. (So you understand, the speaker is little and short.)

So you understand, the speaker is little and short. What does it mean "in proportion"? Just literally, the speaker is little and the mini cooper is little and the car is the right one for the speaker?

Comment: Proportion is a measure (whether accurately determined or broadly envisioned) of how the ratio between say the sizes of two objects (this can be broadened to less tangible things such as fashions, disasters ...) compares to the ratio between two others. (Little me and my Mini Cooper) is in proportion to (the average man and his Audi A4), and (Arnie and his Humvee). Though the average man might be in the street on the Clapham omnibus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/proportion) defines proportion as,

> the correct or most attractive relationship between the size of
> different parts of the same thing or between one thing and another:
>
> *His feet seem very small in proportion to his body.*
>
> *My head was much nearer the camera than the rest of me so I'm all out
> of proportion.*

So yes, you can say, 'We are in proportion.'

'I feel as if it's proportion... ' is *less* idiomatic but perfectly acceptable if the speaker is groping for the right expression.

Comment: "I feel as if it's proportion..." seems wrong to me. How would you complete that sentence? *Proportionate* would be okay.

Comment: @nnnnnn It isn't perfect, but someone is *speaking*. It looks as if he is groping for the right word. I *couldn't* complete that sentence, but neither could he! We often speak ungrammatically. This seems OK to me: "My painting always lacks something. What is it? Is it perspective? Foreshortening?" "I feel as if it's proportion: everything's the wrong size relative to everything else!"